# Is there a system table that updates and returns its row based on a query?

Tags: sql, oracle

DUAL is a system table that is used to get constants and results of system functions.

[image: This works]

However it only has one column named "dummy" and only a row with X value in it so this doesnt work:

[image: This, not so much.]

My question is, is there a system table that can pull this trick off? A (single-column) table that returns a row regardless of how its one column is queried, with the value in the where clause.

Comment: Values can't be transferred from WHERE clause to SELECT list.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do violates how SQL works.  However, if you always wnat to return exactly one row from a "table", you can use aggregation with no `group by`:

```
select max(dummy)
from dual
where dummy = '5'
```

The returns value is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be easier to suggest *something* if you explained what problem you are trying to solve.

As you asked:

> A (single-column) table that returns a row regardless of how its one column is queried, with the value in the where clause.

```
SQL> select dummy from dual where dummy = '5' or 1 = 1;

D
-
X

SQL>
```

- dual is a (single-column) table
- this query returned a row
- value (`'5'`) is in its `where` clause
- I presume that "regardless of how its one column is queried" is also satisfied

Answer (score 0):

Why "where clause"?

```
SELECT '5' AS dummy FROM dual

DUMMY|
-----|
5    |
```